# What exactly is this lea supposed to do?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm solving a school assignment and so far everything has been quite simple. However, I encountered the following piece of code:

```
mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax    ;load pointer function argument into eax
mov (%eax), %eax       ;dereference the pointer
test %eax, %eax        ;
sete %dl               ;test if it was 0
lea 0x1(%eax), %ecx    ;???
mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax    ;load the argument again
mov %ecx, (%eax)       ;store whatever is in ecx on the pointed-to address
...
```

I'm really at my wit's end here, does the register have an address? Way I see it, the lea would store the address of eax (offset by 1) into ecx, but that doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: Without knowing the high-level code this assembler corresponds to, it's going to be difficult to figure out the purpose...

Comment: Indeed, what that `lea` does is `ecx = eax + 1`. Whether or not that makes sense depends on what the code is supposed to do, which isn't particularly clear from the information provided.

Comment: Well that's kind of the point of the task, to figure out what the code does. This is just a snippet of what I thought was necessary to figure out what the lea instuction does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lea 0x1(%eax), %ecx` loads the register `%ecx` with `%eax + 1`. The `lea` instruction is commonly used for arithmetic computations, thanks to the relatively sophisticated addressing modes of this instruction set.

If you do not identify `%eax` as an address, this is likely what is happening here (as Oli says, we don't have enough context to tell).

Comment: That might just be it! So if we had 3 operand instructions, this would be somewhat equal to addi ecx, eax, 1?

Comment: @user2524502 Yes, exactly. Also `lea`, unlike `add`, does not affect the flags, which is sometimes useful to remember when hand-writing assembly. This sometimes allows sequences like `add …; lea …; lea …; jne … /* branch depending on the result of add */`